# How to call a Typescript function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I have a question about this function in TypeScript. How can i call this function?

```
type Fish = { swim: () => void };
type Bird = { fly: () => void };
 
function move(animal: Fish | Bird) {
  if ("swim" in animal) {
    return animal.swim();
  }
 
  return animal.fly();
}
```

I tried for example this

```
move(Fish)
```

or this

```
move(swim)
```

But everything gives me an error.

Comment: Please provide the complete snippets you're trying that are resulting in errors

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: `Fish` is a type, not a variable and for this `move(swim)` you need to provide a swim variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish and Bird are types, you can't pass types as arguments ..

what you should do is create a variable of that type and then call it

Ex:

```
let animal : Fish = { 
           swim: () => {
               console.log("I swim");
           }
 }
 move(animal);
```

Comment: I found the example here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Comment: @VojtaSimek the example is fine, the problem is with your call to function, they don't call it with the type in the example

Comment: So I can not call their function ?

Comment: @VojtaSimek you can call it with a variable and not with a type, Fish is a type in the example while there is no variable declared, you need to declare a variable like i've done in my answer and then call the function with the variable as argument

so you can't do move(Fish) or move(Bird) but you can call move(object)